# Append a text file multiple times to create one big text file for testing

Tags: windows, cmd

I have one text file having 100,000 lines (xyz.txt). I want to append this file 60 times (n times) to another file to create a big text file (big.txt). How can it be done using cmd (command line)?

(I need this for performance/load testing.)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done using a for-loop:

```
for /L %%i in (0,1,%3) do type %1>>%2

:: %1 source file
:: %2 destination file
:: %3 number of inserts
```

You can put this in a batch file and call it like so:

```
append_text.cmd source.txt dest.txt 60
```

This will write the content of source.txt 60 times into dest.txt.

If you want to write this in a command prompt directly then you could write:

```
for /L %i in (0,1,60) do type source.txt>>dest.txt
```

Comment: Would be good to see how this code can be modified to ensure the header is not duplicated.

Comment: @viru Sorry for the late reply, I might have missed the notification. Yes this could be done. In your batch file just call `type source.txt>>dest.txt` once to create the header (and the first set of lines) in the dest.txt file, then change the first parameter from 0 to 1 in the loop to skip the first line of the source file (or how many lines you want to skip): `for /L %i in (1,1,%3) do type source.txt>>dest.txt`